# Battery diagnostic tool at Apple Genius Bars

Tags: iphone, battery, apple-store

I have a one-year old iPhone 5 and it's battery performance has dramatically decreased over the last few months. As I could use my iPhone for over 24 hours a year ago, the lifespan has halved by now.

I'm not interested in the reason why or answers like "*it's normal*", but in the following. A friend of mine told me Apple has a diagnostic tool at it's Genius bars to check the health of the battery. Is this a rumor or is the tool real? And if so, can it be bought by  consumers (I don't thinks so, but you never know :))

Comment: Apple has announced a program to replace batteries from early iPhone 5. You should see if your phone's serial number is included.

Comment: iPhone 5 battery replacement details can be found at https://www.apple.com/support/iphone5-battery/

Comment: There is a known issue with iPhone 5 batteries to visit the following site to check if your phone has a dodgy battery !! https://www.apple.com/uk/support/iphone5-battery/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is real.
One of the Genius perform the diagnosis right in front of me. If memory serves, it goes like this:

1. With your iPhone, or whichever iDevice, connected to the Apple Store's wifi, "Apple Store", open Safari, and connect to URL "diagnosis.apple.com" (or diagnostics)
2. A page will show up, with a text entry bar for the Genius to enter a verification code.
3. The genius will pull up a page from his "Genius" iPod touch, (the one with bar code scanner), and possibly clicked a certain icon, which leads him to the verification code. I assume that the verification code is changing over time.
4. After entering the code into your device, there goes the diagnosis page.

In the brief moment he was looking at my iPhone, I was able to see the maximum capacity (by design) and the capacity left, which is 98% in my case. By this figure he will determine whether your iPhone's battery needs a replacement. If not, he will suggest that you restore the iPhone and the battery issue (if any) will likely go away.

I asked the Genius whether that's a secret page, he just calmly answered that it's just a tool for them to do the diagnosis.

So no, you cannot purchase it, as it is simply an internal webpage which requires Genius verification.

---

As a side note, informed by the same Genius, the easiest way to tell whether your battery/system has problem with battery life is to go to `Settings - General - Usage` in your device.

Look at the "Time Since Last Full Charge" section, it tells you how long the device has been used and how long it has been on standby. If the two figure are very close, e.g. 2 hours for usage and 2 hours 10 minutes for standby. But you clearly remember that you haven't been "using" the device for 2 hours, but only let in stay in sleep mode. This means that something running in the background is draining your power, and your device is never sleeping.

In this case, the Genius will suggest that you restore the iPhone (and restore from iCloud or iTunes if you wish) and the problem will most likely go away.

==============

**Update**

After visiting the Genius bar again, I saw a genius helping a customer on similar issue and I took a picture.

[image: genius iPad]

Instead of connecting to some normal URL in safari, a link in the format of "diags://#####" would be generated and visited by the device in question.

Comment: This is mostly correct.  The Genius basically initiates a ticket, which creates a ticket number.  The customer then visits diags://1234 (assuming ticket number 1234) on their iOS device and the built in diagnostic app is launched.  The diagnostic app runs and relays its report back to Apple's system, which the Genius can then check.

Comment: Actually, in the US I've gotten self support from Apple's web site and it generated the ticket number automatically for me. You can of course call AppleCare or visit AppleCare in the stores (which is the genius staff) to run the diagnostic as well. It's a service, so short of buying yourself a self-servicing account you will need to get Apple to initiate each test.

Comment: I having the same problem with my iPhone. I tried the steps shown above, i opened up apple store and opened the safari. input the dianostics.apple.com or diagnosis.apple.com but the browser is saying "safari cannot open the page because the server cannot be found.

Comment: @Cris You don't enter "http: //diags" - enter "diags://43252" or whatever somewhat random ticket number Apple enables for your diagnostic run. You can't just run this without them enabling a slot for your test results to get analyzed.

Answer (score 12):

https://getsupport.apple.com/Issues.action

You can run the diagnostics tool there. My phone has been randomly shutting down when it still has around 20 - 30% battery left, and after running the diagnostics tool it said my iPhone 5 has a 'Power issue'.

It doesn't give much more information than that, but I have an appointment at the store this week. I'm not sure what they will do, as I've had it now for just over a year.

Comment: What happens is if the tool says your hardware has a problem or the battery is "in the red" in terms of capacity remaining, they offer a replacement and inform you of the cost. The warranty pays for some battery repairs and not others. It's detailed in apple.com/legal for the country where the device was sold. Generally, you pay if the battery made it to the expected life or it's outside the coverage period.

Comment: Just tried. Doing that it sends a text with a special link, however it doesn't let you view the results it just sends them to apple and then you have to either click the button to call apple (Which costs money, or send in for support etc). Based on this thread sounds like in the past they showed the results on screen where is now they just send them to apple so they can diagnose.

Answer (score 8):

You can get the battery information that the Apple Genius gets by installing [iBackupBot](http://www.icopybot.com/itunes-backup-manager.htm).

1. Open iBackupBot
2. Plugin your iOS device
3. Select your device under Devices on the left 
   [image: Devices]
4. Select More Information
5. See Battery details - your battery is in good health if `FullChargeCapacity` (health of your battery) is near `DesignCapacity`

   [image: Battery diag details]

Comment: I used this earlier this year, but now it is no longer working. Anybody could use this method ???

Answer (score 5):

You can get access to the diagnostic data that the iOS Diagnostics tool sends by following these instructions: http://www.lyonanderson.org/blog/2014/02/06/ios-power-diagnostics/

There's a lot of data to through, but you may find something useful.

Comment: Generally linking to answers is frowned on here as the site can go offline, instead you should post the details and list your source.

Answer (score 3):

Users running jaibroken devices can find this information using an app from Cydia called BatteryLife.

[image: BatteryLife]

Answer (score 1):

The iOS Diag tool is an internal installed app, it displays information such as thermal information, intensive battery information (deeper on iOS 7), call drops, crash reports a few other things that aren't customer facing knowledge.

Mr Rabbit's description is spot on. its also only available on the Apple instore wifi

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same standby and usage time under Settings -> General -> Usage and found a report like this when connecting my iPhone 5S to Xcode:

```
Incident Identifier: 941F209C-EC9B-49B8-B796-F9B07543E9ED
CrashReporter Key:   182e9824ae5047b9b2f2fe5e88777bc89fd945ec
Date:                2014-04-19 02:48:06 -0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 7.1 (11D167)

locationd: com.apple.locationd.NetworkProvider.15fd3dec0    NoIdleSleepAssertion == 255, held for 00:00:03
backboardd: quicklookd[204]-com.apple.mediaremoted.relayxpcmessage [0x17826f4c0]
NoIdleSleepAssertion == 255, held for 00:00:06
backboardd: Music[285]-com.apple.mediaremote.sendremotecommand [0x17007e380]
    NoIdleSleepAssertion == 255, held for 00:00:06
backboardd: Skype[129]-Called by Skype, from unknown method [0x1702708c0]
NoIdleSleepAssertion == 255, held for 00:02:32
backboardd: BriaVoip[132]-132 [0x17026e780]
    NoIdleSleepAssertion == 255, held for 11:01:09
SpringBoard: com.apple.springboard.idle
NoIdleSleepAssertion == 255, held for 00:00:17
dataaccessd: com.apple.persistentconnection[dataaccessd,100,2B8234AA-88C3-4010-BEED-C4C6DB1FC7BC-PendingSimpleTimer(0x1310cb150)]
NoIdleSleepAssertion == 255, held for 00:00:04
apsd: com.apple.apsd-outgoingmessage
NoIdleSleepAssertion == 255, held for 00:00:03
mediaserverd: com.apple.audio.pid-16.keypress.isprewarmed
NoIdleSleepAssertion == 255, held for 00:00:06
mediaserverd: com.apple.audio.VAD Aggregate Device UID 15.isrunning
NoIdleSleepAssertion == 255, held for 05:35:14
mediaserverd: com.apple.audio.AudioSession-132(com.counterpath.bv).isplaying
NoIdleSleepAssertion == 255, held for 09:42:08

Hardware Model: N51AP
Awake Time: 27:14:44 (98084)
Standby Time: 27:14:44 (98084)
Partial Charge: 1
Capacity: 0
Voltage: 3370 mV
```

I don't know if you can force this report to generate, but it was very helpful to determine that Bria (a VOIP soft phone I need for my work) was preventing the device from sleeping, even after rebooting the device. So I force quit the app and now my battery isn't draining overnight.

Comment: This can be found in the `LowBatteryLog` file in General -> Settings -> About -> Diagnostics & Usage -> Diagnostics & Usage Data from your iOS device.

Comment: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1615150 might might have some useful details on potential issues you'll find in the battery log file.

Comment: @bbodenmiller This is a good idea! I don't have that particular log on mine, but I'll try to drain my battery to about 1 or 2% and see if the system generates it.