# Battery problem for Iphone 4

Tags: iphone, ios

I having the same problem with my iPhone running the diagnostics described here:

- [Battery diagnostic tool at Apple Genius Bars](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111027/battery-diagnostic-tool-at-apple-genius-bars)

I tried the steps shown above, i opened up apple store and opened the safari. input the dianostics.apple.com or diagnosis.apple.com but the browser is saying "safari cannot open the page because the server cannot be found.

can you help me?

Comment: *"I tried the steps shown above"* Please provide a link to the question to provide context to your statement.

Comment: @grgarside I'll get a link.

Answer (score 1):

FYI I am not aware that Apple has anything at diagnostics.apple.com or diagnosis.apple.com.

For troubleshooting help with iPhones you can go to

http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/

...or fill us in on exactly what your problem is, step by step. Please be as specific as possible: "my iPhone won't turn on" or "my iphone will naot make a phone call" etc...