# Is there any software for checking hardware in iOS?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, hardware

Is there anything like this in iOS for iDevices ?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

[This question & top answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111027/battery-diagnostic-tool-at-apple-genius-bars) are very relevant.

Basically "yes", but not so much from a customer / end user standpoint.  iOS has a diagnostics tool built in that is accessible from Apple once you give consent.

You can check your iOS device's health using Apple's [main support site](https://getsupport.apple.com/).  From that page you can select iPhone (or iPad), find an issue that would warrant running the diagnostic (I chose power, unexpected shutdown/restart), verify that a restore didn't resolve the issue and then enter your phone number / email address to start the diagnostic process.  Apple will text / email you a link to open.  The link opens the iOS diagnostic tool, which requires you to click through a legal agreement before starting the test.  The test results are sent back to Apple once they finish and you tap "done".  Back on the support site the page will refresh and show any issues that were found with the device as well as support options for resolving them.

Answer (score 2):

There is an free app called SensorMonitor, available from the AppStore, that can be used to check the functionality of various sensors in an iPhone/iPad, for example the compass, accelerometer, etc.

Description taken from the AppStore:

> Description IMPORTANT : Currently, Sensor Monitor doesn't support
> iOS8.
>
> Sensor Monitor displays several sensor raw value of your device. and
> log, use for development!
>
> Also, 'Send over UDP' is available!
>
> available sensor : magnetometer,gps, gyroscope,accelerometer,
> battery,proximity, mic level, touch

A couple of screen shots:

*The Accelerometer and Gyroscope Screen*

[image: Accelerometer and Gyroscope]

*The GPS Screen*

[image: GPS]

Admittedly, it unfortunately does not provide checks for most of the hardware that you mentioned (namely the backlight, ringtone, vibrator or camera).

#### Update August 2017

As per the [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156300/is-there-any-software-for-checking-hardware-in-ios/156328?noredirect=1#comment370998_156328), the app seems to be no longer available.

This was the icon:

[image: Sensor Monitor icon]

This is the about box:

[image: Sensor Monitor about]

Maybe you can contact the developer at [fuzz@fuzz-tech.com](http://mailto:fuzz@fuzz-tech.com).

Here is a web site about the app, [Sensor Monitor](https://www.appdecide.com/app/ios/sensor-monitor/381075251/). It does not support iOS 8, unfortunately.

Comment: thnx for your reply 1+ , but it's not very well or complete I'm looking for something strong

Comment: Apologies. I have updated my answer with more information, but admittedly, the app does not fulfill all of your requirements. I have used this app myself to check/verify second hand iPhones. However, I must admit that an iPhone version of the Android app that you specify would be a handy addition to my checking tools.

Comment: Is this application `SensorMonitor` still exist? I can't found it.

Comment: @vlk - I have updated my answer with more information. Yes, I can not find it in the app store any more :-(

Answer (score 0):

**Phone Doctor Plus** has many diagnostics for the hardware.

iTunes link: 
https://appsto.re/us/GXURH.i

Answer (score 0):

Contact Apple. They can send/text you a free diagnostics file to make sure everything is working fine.

Comment: This answer is perfectly fine.  It contains all the information it needs.  If someone doesn't believe it, they can call Apple themselves to confirm or refute.  I understand that "explanation and context" is often valuable.  But this isn't politics.  We don't need hot air just for its own sake.

Answer (score 0):

This software can make hardware test and diagnostic 
https://idevice.me/3utools-idevice-verification-report/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. Also, since your answer basically only provides a link to an external product, it's at risk of being flagged as SPAM, so it's extra important you include a disclaimer on whether you're affiliated with this product or not.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a utility called Apple Configurator 2 for macOS available from the Mac App Store. It enables you to pull console logs, manage profiles, device info, etc.

[[image: Screenshot of Apple Configurator 2 (macOS) showing iPhone console log.[1]]
Screenshot of Apple Configurator 2 (macOS) showing iPhone console log.

[Apple Configurator 2 on the Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/au/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12)

Comment: How does this test the hardware as asked in the question?

Comment: Using the console to diagnose or troubleshoot any issues eg bad bluetooth stack

Comment: Might help to be more specific about this, not everybody can read/understand log files easily.

Comment: @nohillside with that logic, this question should be flagged as ambiguous https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation/2181#2181

Comment: I agree that the question could be more specific. Nevertheless running a specific hardware verifier is different from scanning through a log, so future site visitors with similar issues might benefit more from your answer if they could see for which log file entries they need to look.

Answer (score -1):

For IOS function check, you can download free app Phone diagnostics from app store: https://itunes.apple.com/vn/app/phone-diagnostics/id1171677218?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

It's easy to use: just launch the app and click on each function test buttons to perform the test.