# Is there available software for MacOS to test iPad functions through USB or other interface?

Tags: ipad, network, wifi, ipados

[Is there any software for checking hardware in iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156300/is-there-any-software-for-checking-hardware-in-ios) mentions a few things for iPhone, some of which may work on iPad.  But I can't get them, because the iPad has no internet.

With WiFi enabled, it connects to the AP but does not display the WiFi icon and TCP apparently does not work.

When I turn off WiFi, I still have LTE, but TCP still does not seem to work.  Safari, Stack Exchange, SpeedTest, etc. However, in a terminal, ping 8.8.8.8 sent and received 18 packets with an average round trip of 20 milliseconds.

Apparently—since I can ping IP addresses and **(update!)** I can surf with Tor—TCP is working but DNS is not.  Yet one of the many things that has already been tried is "Reset Network Settings."

UPDATE: It was not only DNS, but it is still a mystery.  Both problems survived changing the WiFi DNS address to a known good one and another that was probably good, rebooting the iPad, rebooting the WiFi router, and resetting network settings on the iPad.  But the WiFi problem **and the cellular outage** were both fixed by "forgetting" the WiFi and re-joining.

But the question is still whether there is any software that can be run on a Mac to diagnose an IOS device.

Comment: Which iPad do you have and which version of iOS is it running? It is possible to connect an iPad to a network using an Ethernet cable.

Comment: I believe it is iPad Air 2 but I do not have a Lightning to RJ-45 connector.  Probably wouldn't help, anyway.  The ping shows that IP is working, but apparently the TCP layer isn't.  Runs the latest version.  Installed that a few days ago.  Perhaps that's the cause--although it worked fine for a couple of days afterward.

Comment: Sounds like you might just have broken DNS settings. That would make it possible to ping IP-addresses, but you won't be able to access those web sites nor have the WiFi icon as the iPad wouldn't be able to verify internet access. Check your DNS settings in the Settings on the iPad.

Comment: I'll check, but the DNS settings for WiFi and those for cell are different, are they not?  In fact, it is possible to manually put different DNS addresses on each WiFi SSID.  But it has been ten days since I touched the DNS settings, and that was to use Google instead of a rogue spamming outfit on a WiFi in another city.

Comment: Actually, I know of no way to change the DNS for the cell (sorry to say).  And the WiFi, which should be set by DHCP, since I haven't touched this one, is actually all blank.  But that is probably it, since a browser using Tor is working.  Thanks for that hint; I will edit the question.