# How to quickly drain iPhone's charge to compare batteries

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, benchmark

I have two iPhone batteries, and I'm having doubts as to their apparent metrics regarding max charge capacity.

I want to compare their real life performance by putting a high load on them, but I want to do so in a reproducible way and in a way that lets me time the drainage without having to babysit the phone, in order to compare the results.

I have searched for benchmark apps and only found recommendations for Geekbench 3 and Batteryscore, neither which seem to be in my AppStore region. I found Geekbench 4 in my AppStore, but it makes no mention of any battery benchmarks in its description.

How do I go about doing a battery benchmark?

**Update**

Well my 3rd party battery died completely before I could do the experiment. Conclusion: It was garbage that somehow kept a decent charge until its failure.

Comment: Can you clarify what you'd like to do. If you've got two iPhones and you're trying to compare them with each other, what is the benchmark for? Or is it that you're actually trying to compare each of them with some external benchmark? Or are you wanting to establish a benchmark for each of your phones so that you can compare them against their own benchmarks later?

Comment: @Monomeeth I don't have two iPhones. I want to compare the real performance of the two batteries — to each other.

Comment: Ok, so you want to remove/replace the batteries using the same iPhone in order to do some real life testing, and then use the results to see how they compare to each other?

Comment: @Monomeeth That sounds about right. I also plan to compare the ratio of their max capacity metrics with the ratio of their real performance to determine whether my new battery has actually dropped its capacity from 1440 to 400 mAh within 50 charge cycles, while the original has retained about 900 mAh after several hundred cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Geekbench**

I don't have Geekbench 4, but according to this [Primate Labs support page](http://support.primatelabs.com/discussions/geekbench/16757-battery-test-geekbench-4) (1 Feb 2017):

> We're hoping to re-release a battery test for iOS in the future but as of right now we don't have an exact timeline of when that will be available.

So you would need to double-check with them prior to download whether the battery test has been re-released yet (although based on the screenshots I think not).

In terms of the test itself, I do have Geekbench 3 installed on my iPhone and it includes a *Run Battery Benchmark* function.

This is a very lengthy battery test designed to totally discharge a fully charged battery (the app prompts you to plug it in and charge it to 100% before testing). That said, it is actually possible to run the test with only a partially charged battery.

The app also keeps a history of the benchmarks - so it'd be easy for you to keep a separate record of which battery was installed at the time of the benchmark.

My assumption is that when it is re-released, the same functions would be included.

**coconutBattery**

In case you haven't heard of [coconutBattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/), this is an awesome app that you can install on your Mac (if you have one). You can then connect your iPhone to your Mac and this app will show you the battery's current charge, its full charge capacity, and its design capacity (among other things). It also keeps a history, so it'd be easy for you to keep a separate record of which battery was installed at the time you connected your iPhone to your Mac.

If you have a MacBook of some sort it'll give you a whole heap of info relating to your MacBook battery too.

**Other iOS Battery apps**

There are countless iOS battery apps available, most of which I think aren't worth the download.

However, [Battery Life](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/battery-life-check-devices-runtimes/id1080930585?mt=8) is one of the best (make sure it's the one by Robert Tkotzyk - as there have been a couple of *copies* that essentially look exactly the same). I have found this app's *Run Times* to be more accurate than many others. By *Run Times* I mean it provides an estimate of the remaining runtime for various functions (e.g. talk time, browsing, video, etc).

**Do your own 'real life' testing**

Doing some real life testing provides the advantage of determining the exact battery life for your exact scenario (iPhone model, battery, installed apps, etc).

For one possible way you could do this, refer to my answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/274395/168832). As you can see, it's quite involved if you want to ensure accuracy, and it will take some time.

**Summary**

My recommendation would be to [contact Primate Labs](http://www.primatelabs.com/contact/) to seek the current status of again including a battery benchmark test on their iOS app. I think this will do exactly what you want without all the mucking around.

Beyond that, I would try [coconutBattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) out (it's free to download) and give [Battery Life](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/battery-life-check-devices-runtimes/id1080930585?mt=8) a go too.

**NOTE:** - I have no affiliation whatsoever with any of the products described in this answer.

Comment: Thank you. I'll consider contacting them. Regarding real life testing the two biggest hurdles are 1) the load needs to be uniform so that the total uptime is proportional to energy used, and 2) timing the moment the device dies. Perhaps I should just turn on the flashlight and screen brightness and put the phone on a shelf in the evening, and look at the time when the room turns dark...

Comment: You _could_ do that, but one of the reasons I like the proposal in my other answer is that by playing a movie you'll be able to set an alarm etc on another device to let you know when the movie is about to finish. Then you can go back and forth repeating that process and taking note of the charge percentage each time. This way you're not sitting there for hours while testing, and if you do the same process for both batteries you'll have the comparison you need.

Comment: The load will be the same (same device, same movie, same brightness, same ambient temperature). You'll also get an idea of how much the battery drains for each play of the movie, so when you think you've started it for the last time you can set an alarm for a pretty good guess at when it's not too far off from dying. Also, because you're keeping a record of the battery percentage after each play, you've got a number of measurements you can compare and/or benchmark.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea, I might take regular readings after all. I'm not sure though — the reason I'm doing this at all is that I don't trust the reported values and, by extension, the battery gauge. Furthermore, should I be concerned about accuracy when swapping the battery, or is the gauge calibration data stored on-chip in the circuitry of each individual battery?

Comment: Geekbench 4 now has the update

Comment: Thanks for the update (no pun intended). :) It took them longer than I would have liked, but at least they've taken on board ours and others feedback! :)